Asking question to which you know the answer
Is it reasonable that I make questions for which I know the answer?
A couple of examples:
What is Freicoin's annual and per block demurrage rate?
How will Freicoin's fixed supply be initially distributed?

Yes, this is in the StackExchange FAQ
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/11236

For some reason I can't seem to post the above comment as an answer. It gets auto-converted to a comment. First time I'm encountering this feature, and I don't like it. Anyway, it is the right answer.

According to the StackExchange FAQ, answering your own questions is perfectly fine and even encouraged. The idea behind StackExchange is to get answers to the questions, not "ask questions so other people can answer them and get reputation". ;)
